# Can't connect to MariaDB on localhost using DBeaver

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dbeaver

I've just installed `mariadb` on Ubuntu

```
mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

I can connect to the DB using PHP through a local webserver and can connect over the command line. However, I can't get DBeaver to connect from the GUI. I set up a connection using the MariaDB drivers, for `localhost` on port `3306` with the `root` user / pass I use from the cli.

I get this error:

```
Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Any idea if that's a `my.cnf` setting that needs to be changed or is there another setting I'm missing in DBeaver?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61749304/connection-between-dbeaver-mysql worked for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This answer helped: https://serverfault.com/questions/808977/mariadb-refuses-remote-connections

But specifically the comment that pointed out you may need to restart your machine-- running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart` showed that the server had restarted, but the altered IP bindings apparently did not get refreshed until I rebooted the machine.

I changed the line:

`bind-address            = 127.0.0.1`

to

`bind-address            = ::`

Comment: Thanks, had a similar issue on Mac OSX after upgrading Postgres with Brew.

Answer (score 0):

I did around 200 tests and almost 4 hours lost, thanks for the @user101289 solution but the easiest one was just adding a password to the user.

Leaving the code so maybe it could be useful for any other person:

```
ALTER USER 'userName'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'New-Password-Here';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Hope it works for more people