# Connection between DBeaver & MySQL

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I use `DBeaver` to watch an SQL database on `MySQL` **8+**.

Everything is working, but sometimes, opening `DBeaver`, I have the following error message :

```
Public Key Retrieval is not allowed
```

And then, `DBeaver` can't connect to `MySQL`.

In order to fix this problem, I have to reconfigure `MySQL`.

Is there any simplest way to fix this problem ?

Comment: can elaborate what you have done so far started a new connection in dbeaver and add ssl support and added your crt file in the appropriate textbox and then comes the error?

Comment: I solved this problem with below settings
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMBl6.jpg)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you try explicitly allowing public key retrieval in DBeaver?
In the connection settings, SSL tab you can find it

[image]

This is in case you are using SSL, otherwise in the same screen you can disable SSL by unchecking "use SSL" and "require SSL"

Answer (score 111):

Change the settings on `Dbeaver`:

1. Right click your connection, choose `Edit Connection`
2. On the `Connection settings` screen (main screen) click on `Edit Driver Settings`
   [image]
3. Click on `Connection properties`
4. Right click the `User Properties` *area* and choose `Add new property`
5. Add two properties: `useSSL` and `allowPublicKeyRetrieval`
   [image]
6. Set their values to `false` and `true` respectively by double clicking on the `value` column
7. Save and test the connection.

Hopefully it should work!

Comment: It gives me an error said: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) after trying your answer.

Comment: It works through the `Drivers properties` tab.

Comment: You're awesome!

Comment: The interface has changed in 21.3.5. The `edit connection` context menu item now opens a MySQL dialog. In this dialog the three referenced items are not *user properties* any longer. They're in the main list of driver properties. So, you just have to find them in the list and adjust accordingly.

Comment: You also get it using `useSSL=true` either.

Comment: I was able to use this solution over the accepted to avoid having to specify certificates needed for SSL :)

Comment: Both `allowPublicKeyRetrieval` and `useSSL` set to `true` did the trick in my case, with MySQL 8.

Comment: Though UI is different, this still works for DBeaver 23.2.4.

Answer (score 37):

Edit Connection

click second tab `Driver Properties`

Change property `allowPublicKeyRetrieval` to `True`

`Connection settings` or `Driver properties`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Ratish Bansal's solution works for me on MacOS Mojave, and **after that**, I always get a timezone error. The solution for that is to set my local timezone in the `connection settings`:

[image]